# Passar conteúdo de CSV para uma tabela SQLite

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, csv

Tenho um arquivo CSV com registros de alunos. Gostaria de subir esses registros para uma tabela `aluno` no SQLite.

Como posso realizar essa operação?

Comment: Se servir em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672074/import-csv-file-to-sqlite-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Tu tem passar os dados para objeto antes de tudo.
Depois tu insere os dados no banco. Existe um framework para trabalhar com banco o **SQLite**.

Para passar os dados de .CSV para objeto tu vai ter que ler linha por linha do CSV e quebrar cada linha pelo divisor dos dados (ex. **;**).
Pega cada dado e insere no seu objeto.

```
Exemplo.

CSV
jose ; turma 301 ; 10 anos
joao ; turma 401 ; 11 anos

Stirng csv = leituraDeArquivoCSV();
List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

while(data.hasNext()){ 
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
    String[] data = csv.split(";");
    aluno.setNome(data[0]); 
    aluno.setTurma(data[1]); 
    aluno.setIdade(data[2]); 

    alunos.add(aluno);
}
```

Agora é pegar o objeto **alunos** e salvar normalmente.